# Dailymotion stop video from iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe, dailymotion-api

I am trying to make a slider with multiple video providers, and I need to make videos stop on slide-change.
I have managed to work on vimeo and youtube, withouht using any extra api calls just with

```
$('.youtube-iframe')[index].contentWindow.postMessage('{"event":"command","func":"' + 'stopVideo' + '","args":""}', '*');

$('.vimeo-iframe')[index].contentWindow.postMessage('{"method":"pause"}', '*');
```

I have searched for dailymotion but I couldnt get an example to make iframe stop using their API

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You seems to use the pause method on vimeo
Did you try using the pause() method from the dailymotion player api ?
-> http://www.dailymotion.com/doc/api/player.html

Comment: I've tried the postMessage('{"method":"pause"}', '*') with dailymotion but didn't work

Comment: As mentioned in [api-reference](http://www.dailymotion.com/doc/api/player.html#api-reference), "_API methods are simple string with an optional parameter. To call a method, just pass the method name as string using the chosen API mode_".
Something like `$('.dailmotion-iframe')[index].contentWindow.postMessage('pause', '*');` should make it.

Answer (score 1):

Well it seems possible, the iframe needs to be loaded with &api=postMessage, then you get a DOM reference to the iframe and do:

```
iframe.contentWindow.postMessage('play', '*');
```

And it works.

Answer (score 0):

The working code is:

```
iframe.contentWindow.postMessage('{"command":"pause","parameters":[]}', "*");
```

Used in code of [dailymotion-sdk-js](https://github.com/dailymotion/dailymotion-sdk-js/blob/0f5d595aa51b00fc7c4e13497505c4a0d1a902c2/src/core/player.js#L200-L209)
.

But you need to define `api=postMessage` parameter in iframe's src